# ASP RadioButton Client Event Not Triggering

Tags: asp.net, javascript, radio-button, client-side

I'm dynamically generating radio buttons in my code behind and assigning javascript to them as they are created.  This javascript will change the value in a hidden field for when a postback is eventually triggered (autopostback on the buttons is disabled).  I am using the exact same method with ASP ImageButtons and it works fine but when I do it with the radio buttons the event never triggers the Javascript.  I suspect that I may be using the wrong event name but I have tried several (onclick, onCheckedChanged, etc).

Here is a sample of the VB.NETcode - how come this works fine with my button but not my radiobutton!

```
//This is my hidden field
ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(Me.UniqueID & "_someVariable", "")
Dim radDefault As RadioButton = New RadioButton()
radDefault.GroupName = "radio buttons"
radDefault.AutoPostBack = False
//This adds the Javascript to set the hidden field with an onClick event
radDefault.Attributes.Add("onClick", "document.forms[0]." & Me.UniqueID & "_someVariable.value='0';document.forms[0].submit();")
```

The code is simplified as the button generation is actually through an iterator but the same properties are given to each generated radio button.

Comment: The code looks fine. Is the script not running at all? Or is it trying to run and throwing an error? Or perhaps there is a syntax error which prevents it from running? Is the script you generate actually rendered to the browser?

Comment: Hey Ray, 

How would I know if the script is running or if it's throwing an error?  I'm using Visual Studio 2008 - is it possible to debug the javascipt that is rendered?  The following is rendered to the browser - it looks fine:

<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radio buttons" value="ctl00" onclick="document.forms[0].__Page_someVariable.value='0';document.forms[0].submit();" />

Comment: One trick is to preface your script with "alert(1);" - if it is trying to run, you will see the alert box. If you are using IE, check the left side of the status bar for a script error. If Firefox, use Firebug for much better info.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with Firebug - installed it and it looks like the script is running fine.  I'm now thinking it must be something to do with page lifecycle overwriting the value.  My other use of this was attaching the attribute to a button and then storing the value in the session when the button was pressed.  In this case I attached the attribute to the radiobuttons which don't cause postback and tried to store the value in the session when a button was pressed.  I debugged to confirm that the behaviour followed the same pattern but the value doesn't seem to be in my hidden field anymore.

Comment: Hey Ray,

I've solved the issue now - the postback caused by pressing the button was actually clearing the value of the hidden field (different behaviour from assigning the javascript to a button).  Cheers for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the postback caused by pressing the button was actually clearing the value of the hidden field (different behaviour from assigning the javascript to a button)